# java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID

Tags: java

If I passed in timezone "EST", it will have

"java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID" error, but If I pass in ZoneID like ""America/Mexico_City"", it works good, my question is why three-letter time zone IDs dont work? how to solve this problem?

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-10-25T12:15:30");
System.out.println(localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.of(String.valueOf(ZoneId.of("EST").getRules().getOffset(LocalDateTime.now())))).toEpochMilli());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs of [`ZoneId.SHORT_IDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#SHORT_IDS):

> This map allows the IDs to continue to be used via the `of(String, Map)` factory method.

So, use that factory method:

```
ZoneId.of("EST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)
```

Or, of course, use the aliased value directly:

```
ZoneId.of("-05:00")
```

Or, if you actually mean "the time zone in New York", in which daylight savings is observed:

```
ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
```